# Script that uses google-drive-ocamlfuse fails when run through Rundeck

Tags: google-drive-api, rundeck

I have a script that runs fine when run directly from the shell of the server hosting Rundeck.  It uses google-drive-ocamlfuse to mount my google drive to a local directory, creates a folder in the directory, and then unmounts.

```
name=New-Folder-Name
google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/user/mygoogledrive/
mkdir /home/user/mygoogledrive/$name
fusermount -u /home/user/mygoogledrive/
```

If I try to run this as an ad hoc command in Rundeck:

`sudo ./var/lib/rundeck/scripts/create-folder.sh`

... it errors out with:

```
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: chromium-browser: not found
/bin/sh: 1: open: not found
Cannot retrieve auth tokens.
Failure("Error opening URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=REDACTING-PERSONAL-INFO")
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/mygoogledrive/New-Folder-Name’: No such file or directory
fusermount: failed to unmount /home/home-db/mygoogledrive: Invalid argument
```

I am new to Rundeck and am not yet comfortable with permissions and I don't have a good sense of how a command is being run on the server by Rundeck.  It must be accessing and executing the file, given the error output, but maybe there are some limitations in the environment due to permissioning that doesn't allow for the use of certain libraries need by google-drive-ocamlfuse?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To use `sudo` on a target remote node, you need to set the `sudo` [parameters](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#secondary-sudo-password-authentication). Otherwise, if you need to use `sudo` locally, the easier way is to use [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution) plugin in your Rundeck instance.